# JQuery change text

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I have a simple task to change text on the button after it being pressed. Here is my script:

```
$(".recent").on("click", 'button', function () {
        $(this).closest($("li")).find($(".content")).slideToggle();
        if ($(this).text="Show content") {
            $(this).text("Hide content");
        } else {
            $(this).text("Show content");
        }
    });
```

When I press the button, text changes to "Hide content". But when i press button again, it does not change back to "Show content". 
Guess it's about something simple... Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `===` for comparison .You were using `=` which assigns value.
Also `.text()` is a method

```
$(".recent").on("click", 'button', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.content').slideToggle();
    if ($(this).text() === "Show content") {
        $(this).text("Hide content");
    } else {
        $(this).text("Show content");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use equivalence `===` instead of assignment `=` and use text() instead of text

```
$(".recent").on("click", 'button', function () {
        $(this).closest($("li")).find($(".content")).slideToggle();

        if ($(this).text() === "Show content") {
            $(this).text("Hide content");
        } else {
            $(this).text("Show content");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Also, he was using `$(this).text` (returns a `Function`) instead of `$(this).text()` (returns a `String`)

Comment: There's no need to pass jQuery objects into `closest` and `find`. They both take selector strings.

Answer (score 1):

`.text()` is a method, so you have to call it to get and set the text:

```
$(".recent").on("click", 'button', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.closest("li").find(".content").slideToggle();

    if ($this.text() === "Show content") {
        $this.text("Hide content");
    } else {
        $this.text("Show content");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the `.text` is a **method**, therefore needs to be followed by a `()`. Also, for equality, use `==` **not** `=`, single `=` is for assignments.

Try this:

```
$(".recent").on("click", 'button', function () {
    $(this).closest($("li")).find($(".content")).slideToggle();
    if ($(this).text() == "Show content") {
        $(this).text("Hide content");
    } else {
        $(this).text("Show content");
    }
});
```